Regularize a Laplace Operator on a 2D strip with Perioidic Boundary Conditions
I am trying to solve a PDE, and I simplified it to a point where I can find a Green function for the following operator:
$$\nabla^2G(r-r',\theta-\theta')=-\delta(r-r')\delta(\theta-\theta'). $$
Note, the Laplacian has no scale factors, so it looks like it is Cartesian, but the system is $2\pi$ periodic in the $\theta$ variable! Thus the second delta function is also periodic and we can define a Fourier Series $$f(r,\theta)=\sum_n a_n(r) e^{in\theta}$$ to solve recast this problem in an alternative form. It results in the modified Helmholtz equation:
$$\Big(\partial_r^2-n^2\Big)G_n(r-r')=-\frac{\delta(r-r')}{2\pi}$$
We can now apply a Fourier transform and arrive at a solution for $G_n(k)$, then use the residue theorem to transform back to position space. The final result looks something like (maybe some factors of 2 or $\pi$ errors):
$$G(r-r',\theta-\theta')=\frac{1}{4\pi}\sum_{n\neq 0}\frac{\exp\Big(n\big(i(\theta-\theta')-|r-r'|\Big)}{n}+\frac{1}{2\pi} $$
My question I try to find the solution of this type of equation, but with a source term $J(r,\theta)$. The integral is approximated numerically. My Green function appears to be blowing up though, and I am wondering if a regularization is in order or appropriate to handle this? Or is there a reason my analysis is off?

I will slightly modify your notation so that there will be no confusion with polar coordinates. Your Green's function is:
$$
-\Delta G(x,y) = \delta(x)\delta(y)
$$
with $y$ $2\pi$-periodic. Indeed, going to Fourier space is a good idea:
$$
G(x,y) = \frac1{2\pi}\sum_{k_y}\int\frac{e^{i(k_xx+k_yy)}}{k_x^2+k_y^2}\frac{dk_x}{2\pi}
$$
with $k_y\in\mathbb Z^*$. You just made a mistake in your formula. The Green's function for Helmholtz' equation in 1D is rather:
$$
G_n(x) = \frac{e^{-|nx|}}{2|n|}
$$
so the Green's function is (assuming 0 mean value up to gauge):
$$
\begin{align}
G(x,y) &= \frac1{2\pi}\sum_{n\neq 0}\frac{e^{-|nx|+iny}}{2|n|}\\
&= -\frac1{4\pi}\ln\left(1-2e^{-|x|}\cos(y)+e^{-2|x|}\right)
\end{align}
$$
using the MacLaurin series of the logarithm:
$$
-\ln(1-t) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{t^n}n
$$
There is no regularisation needed in Fourier space. The series converges absolutely in the domain excluding a neighbourhood of the sources at $x=0,y\in 2\pi\mathbb Z$, so mathematically, there is no ambiguity. As a sanity check, you can verify that as $x,y\to0$, you recover the 2D Coulomb potential:
$$
G(x,y)\sim-\frac1{4\pi}\ln(x^2+y^2)
$$

Turns out I simply did the residue theorem too hastily... I'll just include a few steps.
The function we need to FT is:
$$\frac{e^{ik(r-r')}}{k^2+n^2} $$
The poles are at: $k_\pm=\pm i|n|$. The sign on $r-r'$ determines which contour you'd want to use for Jordan's lemma (the arc in the lower or upper complex plane), and these determine the poles. The sign difference leads us to:
$$\propto\frac{e^{-|n|\cdot|r-r|}}{2|n|} $$
I was using $n$ in the exponent, so of course it blew up.
